# How to call cross program function when I have information of program-id and instruction only not the account-info?

Tags: solana-program, cpi, account-data, invoke

I am calling **Program B** from **Program A** and all I know is program-id of **Program-B** and instruction message (not the account info's that will be going to read/update in Program-B execution).

In this situation, How should I call the cross-program-invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the account infos, you *cannot* do a cross-program invocation.

Since you have the instruction creator, however, you can investigate the source code to see the accounts passed in and their order.

This is a longstanding issue on Solana with the `invoke` API.  Since you're declaring the account pubkeys in the instruction, the runtime should be able to find and pull out the required accounts.  It just hasn't been implemented unfortunately.